# Hide Admin Menu Based on Store Default Country

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, admin-panel, adminform

I need help on hiding the Customer Feedback - Article Menu if the default country is not JP.

My code is not working.

**Plugin/RemoveCustomerFeedback.php**

```
<?php

namespace Thecoachsmb\Mymodule\Plugin;

class RemoveCustomerFeedbackMenu
{
    protected $_request;
    protected $_authSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_authSession = $authSession;
    }

    public function afterGetMenu(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder $subject,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Menu $menu
    ) {
        $defaultCountry = $this->_authSession->getUser()->getDefaultCountry();
        if ($defaultCountry != 'JP') {
            $menu->remove('Thecoachsmb_Mymodule::customerfeedback');
        }
        return $menu;
    }
}
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder">
    <plugin name="remove_customerfeedback_menu" type="Thecoachsmb\MyModule\Plugin\RemoveCustomerFeedbackMenu" />
</type>
```

**etc/menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
  <menu>
    <add id="Thecoachsmb_Blog::report_elements"
         title="Thecoachsmb Blog"
         translate="title"
         module="Thecoachsmb_Blog"
         sortOrder="15"
         parent="Magento_Reports::report"
         resource="Magento_Backend::admin"/>
    <add id="Thecoachsmb_Mymodule::customerfeedback"
         title="Customer Feedback - Article"
         translate="title"
         module="Thecoachsmb_Mymodule"
         sortOrder="20"
         parent="Magento_Reports::report"
         action="thecoachsmb_mymodule/customerfeedback"
         resource="Magento_Backend::admin"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After amount of time researching the solution of this. I realized that creating a custom menu was the best solution. Please refer to [Menu not showing for custom role in custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367008/menu-not-showing-for-custom-role-in-custom-module)

Answer (score 0):

When creating the plugin for a class function, there must be two conditions fulfilled:

- The class name for which we are creating plugin must be same in the class mentioned in **<type name="">** section in **di.xml** file and in the the plugged-in function in plugin class.
- The plugged-in function name must exist in the original class.

I checked the **\Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder** class and could not find **getMenu()** function in this class.

Please verify that:

- You are creating plugin for the correct class
- The function you are trying to create plugin must be present in the original class.